# Rails check if IRB console or webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

In my model I would like to check if the app is running inside IRB consol or as a website?

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def xmethod
    if !isIRBconsol
      self.user_id = UserSession.find.user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you say why you want this?  The larger problem might have a better solution.

Comment: I want to set user_id field of a model before_save. Because UserSession does not exists in IRB i try smth like that. Better solutiom?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just `if defined?(IRB)`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to always work depending on your scope, I've settled on `Rails.const_defined?('Console')` for now.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hack, but it should work:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def am_i_in_irb?
    self.private_methods.include? 'irb_binding'
  end
end
```

But as Kathy Van Stone said above, this is probably something that has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
unless self.private_methods.include? 'irb_binding'
   #put your rufus scheduling here
end
```