# Best way to not run rufus-scheduler when starting a rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I use rufus-scheduler to run some periodic tasks, but they are extremely annoying to have in the rails console when I just want to test things.  Is there an easy way to stop all rufus-scheduler tasks when starting a console automatically?

In the code that starts the scheduler if i can check that i am just in a rails console I can not run them, or if there is a way to run some callbacks when the console starts I can also shut them down there.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [Rails check if IRB console or webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329729/rails-check-if-irb-console-or-webpage):

```
unless self.private_methods.include? 'irb_binding'
  #put your rufus scheduling here
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when I used rufus-scheduler and delayed-jobs.

I used this:

```
unless defined?(Rake) || defined?(IRB)
  # your code here
end
```

Tested in Rails 4

Answer (score 2):

As per the revised documentation for rufus-scheduler [here](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#avoid-scheduling-when-running-the-ruby-on-rails-console):

> If you don't want rufus-scheduler to kick in when running the Ruby on
>   Rails console or invoking a rake task, you can wrap your initializer
>   in a conditional:
>
> ```
> unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake'
>   # your code here
> end
> ```