# rufus-scheduler double scheduling when accessing rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I am using rufus-scheduler in rails application. My application is running on passenger with apache server.When i login on remote server and doing some stuff in rails console then rufus-scheduler behaving weirdly.Some time it running job 2 times and sometime not running job at all. I am using rails 3.2.6 with ruby 1.9.3 and rufus-scheduler version is 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing weird, your `rails console` is spinning a new scheduler instance.

There is this old Probably [Best way to not run rufus-scheduler when starting a rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890551/best-way-to-not-run-rufus-scheduler-when-starting-a-rails-console)

The documentation of rufus-scheduler has summarized it under: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#avoid-scheduling-when-running-the-ruby-on-rails-console

Comment: Thanks for the help.Double scheduling job error has been resolved.